# Find if a phrase is 'generally rare' in English

Tags: nltk, wordnet, corpus, keyword-extraction

I want to extract rare words from text. not rare in that text but generally rare in English.
Is there an NLTK module that uses a large corpus that can answer such a query?

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know the only available corpus is for Dutch with alipo, I think you should build your own one.